# Is there some tools to implement "Code first" approach on Android

Tags: java, android, entity-framework, orm, code-first

**Microsoft** provides very interesting approach on theirs ORM Entity Framework which called **"Code first"**.When database creates from your code and business logic automatically. Is there **some tools** to implement "Code first" approach on Android?

Answer (score -2):

I'm sure you can use UML and Code Generators to achieve similar. Rarely useful though.

Comment: This is called "model first".